# Gay-Berne potential in Mathematica

Tags: physics, chemistry

[Cross-posting from Physics SE.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/697024/unable-to-recreate-plot-for-anisotropic-gay-berne-potentials-from-paper)
I am trying to make a plot of the Gay-Berne potential using Mathematica. I am following [this paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.441483) and I am trying to recreate Fig. 2. This is figure 2:

[image]

To save time, the equations from the paper are as follows:

The potential energy of interaction is
$$V(u_1,u_2,\mathbf{r})=4\epsilon(u_1,u_2)\left( \left[ \frac{\sigma (u_1,u_2,\mathbf{\hat{r}})}{r} \right]^{12}-  \left[ \frac{\sigma (u_1,u_2,\mathbf{\hat{r}})}{r} \right]^{6}\right) $$
where $\chi = (\sigma_{\parallel}^2-\sigma_{\perp}^2)/(\sigma_{\parallel}^2+\sigma_{\perp}^2)$
and $$\sigma(u_1,u_2,\mathbf{\hat{r}}) = \sigma _0 \left(1- \frac{1}{2}\chi \left \{ \frac{(\mathbf{\hat{r}}\cdot u_1 + \mathbf{\hat{r}}\cdot u_2)^2}{1+\chi(u_1\cdot u_2)} +\frac{(\mathbf{\hat{r}}\cdot u_1 - \mathbf{\hat{r}}\cdot u_2)^2}{1-\chi(u_1\cdot u_2)} \right\} \right)^{-1/2}$$
and
$$\epsilon (u_1,u_2) = \epsilon _0 [1-\chi ^2 (u_1\cdot u_2)^2]^{-1/2}$$

This is my Mathematica code for it:

```
spar=3; sperp=1; e0=1; s0=1;
chi=(spar^2-sperp^2)/(spar^2+sperp^2); 
e[u1_,u2_]=e0*(1-chi^2*Dot[u1,u2]^2)^(-1/2)

sigma[u1_,u2_,r_]=s0*(1-0.5*chi((Dot[r/(Dot[r,r])^(1/2),u1]+Dot[r/(Dot[r,r])^(1/2),u2])^2/(1+chi*Dot[u1,u2]) + \
(Dot[r/(Dot[r,r])^(1/2),u1]-Dot[r/(Dot[r,r])^(1/2),u2])^2/(1-chi*Dot[u1,u2])
V[u1_,u2_,r_]=4e[u1,u2]*([sigma[u1,u2,r/Dot[r,r]^(1/2)]/(Dot[r,r]^(1/2))]^12-[sigma[u1,u2,r/Dot[r,r]^(1/2)]/(Dot[r,r]^(1/2))]^6)
```

[image]

My orientation vectors $\hat{u_1},\hat{u_2}$ are $v1,v2$ in the above code. What I am trying to recover is the end-to-end potential energy, but clearly, I am not even going below zero. If I try to get the side-by-side potential energy, by writing $v1=\{0,1,0\},v2=\{0,1,0\}$, I get the following plot:

[image]

Where am I going wrong in the reproduction of this potential? Is something incorrect about how I am setting up my parameters?

Comment: Could you upload Figure 2 as well?

Comment: Please, do not post your code as screenshots, but copy-paste it from Mathematica.

Comment: Also, try with ``PlotRange->{-2, 1}`` in the first plot. I suspect you might be going below zero but you just can't see it at this zoom level.